# Rounding from a double to the next 100

Tags: c#

I am trying to round float values to the next 100 int. For example:

If the value is `128.27`, the rounding method would round it to `200`.

If the value is `589.62`, the rounding method would round it to `600`.

Et cetera.

Here is what I am using so far:

```
    private static int RoundValueToNext100(double value) {
        int result = (int)Math.Round(value / 100);
        if (value > 0 && result == 0) {
            result = 1;
        }
        return (int)result * 100;
    }
```

However, this method doesn't actually round to the 100, and instead rounds to a non-100 value, though it is an integer.

I was wondering why this would be, and if you could give me some pointers - thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't 128.27 be rounded to `100`, instead of `200` ?

Comment: I am trying to round it to the next 100, since this is a Legend grapher, I would like it not chop values off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is Ceiling and not Rounding.

Something like this:

```
double value = ...
int rounded = ((int)Math.Ceiling(value / 100.0)) * 100;
```

Comment: Thank you! You learn something new every day, even on mathematical terminology! I can't believe I didn't think of that.

Comment: Upon further testing, this actually did not work as intended. My value is still not rounded to its respective 100th. My code:             `float value = (max - min);`  `int ceiling = ((int)Math.Ceiling(value / 100.0)) * 100;` `int step = ceiling / numberOfItems;`

Comment: What is the 'value' value you are getting? (max-min) = ?

Comment: The value is `1201.046951`

Comment: :) yep, as i just checked, ((int)Math.Ceiling(1201.046951 / 100.0)) * 100; returns 1300

Comment: Thank you. It was indeed an error on my part with a separate piece of code using this method, but I have fixed it. Here is the result of your help: http://puu.sh/6jKVt/1128a40d50.jpg

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the intended effect, use `Math.Ceiling` instead, it rounds up to the nearest whole number, instead of up or down depending the first non-significant digit:

```
private static int RoundValueToNext100(double value) {
    return (int)(Math.Ceiling(value/100) * 100);
}
```

As for the function not returning multiples of 100 - that is impossible with the code you give.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are rounding up, this looks like it works for me

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(RoundValueToNext100(589.62));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static int RoundValueToNext100(double value)
    {
        int result = (int)Math.Round(value / 100, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

        if (value > 0 && result == 0)
        {
            result = 1;
        }
        return (int)result * 100;
    }
```

Comment: Does not work; 128 will round down to 100. Rounding up applies only to .5 and up, not every decimal. You need Ceiling for that.